# Dump current local variables in C++ Builder (or perform search in them)

Tags: c++builder, rad-studio

I'm debugging game written in C. There are loads of local variables. When I have breakpoint to check particular place in the code - there is no search in Local Variables window and it's very hard to find something fast. I wonder is there a possibility to copy all current (at this particular breakpoint) local variables to in text format (or better in .xml) so I'll be able to perform fast search upon them? OR maybe there is a way to perform search (filtering) in Local Variables somehow?

[image]

Comment: C++Builder does not have the features you are asking for. Perhaps a better option is to use the [Watch List window](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Watch_List_Window) to watch only the specific variable(s) you are interested in. You can create watches from the [Local Variables window](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Local_Variables_Window).

Comment: 1. watch window has local variables switchable (however no save all is present and [too many watches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62712772/2521214) usually freeze IDE especially big classes and arrays) 2. hoovering mouse above variable in code will show its value (if turned on in IDE) so no need to search for it