# Public symbol '__tpdsc__ void' defined in both module X and Y

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-11-alexandria

Using C++ Builder 11.

I split some files up (in a project that built fine so far) and added them to the project individually.

Since then, and only when compiling 32-bit (not 64 bit), I get this weird warning:

> [ilink32 Warning] TCTargets110.Targets(746, 5): Warning: Public symbol
> `'__tpdsc__ void'` defined in both module
> D:\MYPROJECTS\MYPROJECT\CB11\TEMP\WIN32-DEBUG\MYREADCRUMBBAR.OBJ and
> D:\MYPROJECTS\MYPROJECT\CB11\TEMP\WIN32-DEBUG\MAIN.OBJ

I have spent hours already trying to figure out what is triggering this.  Very slow compiles are not helping of course.  Aside from the warning the code appears to execute properly

The code builds fine using C++ Builder 2009

Anybody ANY idea ?
I'm tempted to simply revert this change but I'd like to understand this issue better first.

PS. this relates to a custom control that derives from `TCustomControl`

Scares information online seems to hint at destructors, virtual and __fastcall, my destructor looks like this:

```
virtual __fastcall ~MyBreadcrumbBar() {}
```

Comment: the warning just means that you have two or more declarations/definitions of the same identificator name. It usually happens when you include some lib file more than once. You can remedy this when you encapsulate your files in `#ifndef _file_name\r\n #define _file_name\r\n ... here your code ... #endif` for constants sometimes setting them as `static const` helps. You can also turn off this warning either with macros localy in code or in project options...

Comment: Thank you @Spektre but I have include guards in place. `__tpdsc__ void` is also very much *not* in my code.

Comment: In such case it might be also linked instead of included (you know you have more forms in your app sharing the same libs but not included one in another and vice versa). However In case its really the same file then you can ignore this however if not then you can use `namespace` to remedy this. Sometimes manual include before your windows and VCL includes help (but for that you need to reorganize your include files)

Comment: if everything fails use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56980191/2521214 in the right place in your code just change the `W8066` with the correct number of the warning you want to turn off ...

Comment: I suspect this is due to a difference in the clang and classic compilers.  Your 2009 build would be using the classic compiler, the 11 64bit build will use clang, and the 11 32bit build will use either clang or classic according to your settings.  As the 64 bit works try setting your project options for 32bit to use clang (the same as 64 bit).

I have seen a range of strange errors where code compilation is not the same between the clang and classic compilers.

Comment: @RobLambden both 32bit and 64bit are using clang (Builder 11) but you're obviously right about Builder 2009.  So, in this particular case, there's a difference between clang 32bit and clang 64bit.  I just put the two classes together again, to be built in the same *.obj and the warning went away.  It's something deep and undocumented in the linker, we can only guess.  There's no double code and the linker doesn't know which one to pick because clang 64 bit won't have that at all.